# finding the number of triplests (a,b,c) for which (G,*) it is a group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let the set $ G=\lbrace x\in \mathbb{R}|x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0\rbrace $. Find $p$ which is the number of triplets $(a,b,c)$ from $\mathbb{R}^3$ for which $(G,\cdot)$ it is a group. ($\cdot$ is the multiplication of the real numbers).
I do not know how can be $(G, \cdot)$ a group because I learned only groups defined by a binary operation and I do not see this as $x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$ a binary operation.

Comment: There is no $c$ in the definition of $G$.

Comment: As stated, the binary operation is multiplication. The question is about the conditions under which the set of things that satisfy the equation, when multiplied together according to the usual arithmetic of $\mathbb{R}$, satisfy the group axioms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint :**

$G$ can have $0$, $1$, $2$ or $3$ elements. Because $G$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$, it must be $\lbrace 1 \rbrace$ or $\lbrace -1,1 \rbrace$. Now find all the triplets $(a,b,c)$ that give these two possibilities.

Comment: How did you figure this out when $c$ is not defined?

Comment: @Shaun This seems pretty clear that the correct statement is $x^3 + ax^2 + bx+c$. But anyway, my answer also works with the current statement.

Comment: Yes it was c there ,I am sorry for the typing error.

Comment: And thank you @SilverDoe !I solved the problem.

Comment: @mathgirl You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Following TheSilverDoe's hint, one only needs to consider products of three factors equal to $x+1$ or $x-1$ (assuming that there are no non-real complex roots), as well as the  product of $x-1$ with a monic quadratic having a negative discriminant (for the case where there are non-real complex roots).

If $1$ is a real root of multiplicity $3$, then the cubic polynomial must be equal to $(x-1)^3=x^3-3x^2+3x-1$, giving the triplet $(-3,3,-1)$.

If $1$ is a root of multiplicity $2$ and $-1$ is a root of multiplicity $1$, then the cubic polynomial must be equal to $(x-1)^2(x+1)=(x-1)(x-1)(x+1)=(x-1)(x^2-1)=x^3-x^2-x+1$, giving the triplet $(-1,-1,1)$.

If $1$ is a root of multiplicity $1$ and $-1$ is a root of multiplicity $2$, then the cubic polynomial must be equal to $(x-1)(x+1)^2=(x-1)(x+1)(x+1)=(x^2-1)(x+1)=x^3+x^2-x-1$, giving the triplet $(1,-1,-1)$.

If $1$ is a root of multiplicity $1$ and there are also two non-real complex conjugate roots, then the cubic polynomial must be equal to $(x-1)(x^2+dx+e)=x^3+dx^2+ex-x^2-dx-e=x^3+(d-1)x^2+(e-d)x-e$ for some real numbers $d$ and $e$ with $d^2-4e<0$, giving the triplet $(d-1,e-d,-e)$.

So, there are infinitely many triplets $(a,b,c)$ for which $G$ is a group under ordinary multiplication. Of those triplets, only $(-3,3,-1), (-1,-1,1),$ and $(1,-1,-1)$ give a cubic polynomial with no non-real complex roots, and all the other ones give a cubic polynomial with the real root $1$ and two non-real complex conjugate roots.